# Отключить(ограничить) клик на кнопку после нажатия и ограничить количество нажатий на эту кнопку

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить клик на кнопку после нажатия на 5 секунд + ограничить количество нажатий до 5. Спасибо

```
<button class="rebsd" onclick="elementUpdate('.qqqq');">Нажми меня, чтобы обновить блок</button>

<script>
   async function elementUpdate(selector) {
   try {
   var html = await (await fetch(location.href)).text();
   var newdoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
   document.querySelector(selector).outerHTML = newdoc.querySelector(selector).outerHTML;
   console.log('Элемент '+selector+' был успешно обновлен');
   return true;
   } catch(err) {
   console.log('При обновлении элемента '+selector+' произошла ошибка:');
   console.error(err);
   return false;
   }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function elementUpdate(target, selector) {
  const clickCount = parseInt(target.dataset.clickCount) || 0;
  if (clickCount == 5)
  {
    return false;
  }

  target.dataset.clickCount = clickCount + 1;
  target.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => target.disabled = false, 5000);
    
  try {
    var html = await (await fetch(location.href)).text();
    var newdoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    document.querySelector(selector).outerHTML = newdoc.querySelector(selector).outerHTML;
    console.log('Элемент ' + selector + ' был успешно обновлен');
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('При обновлении элемента ' + selector + ' произошла ошибка:');
    console.error(err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="rebsd" onclick="elementUpdate(this, '.qqqq');">Нажми меня, чтобы обновить блок</button>
```